# Every Two -Substitute ; For Space

Tags: batch-file

I have been given this txt file ej:

> -state;of;product-;-201705-;-ID1-;-SOLD-;-4-;-PROD;1-;;

and i need to change it to:

> -state of product-;-201705-;-ID1-;-SOLD-;-4-;-PROD 1-;;

As you can see every two - I need to change ; with an space.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (YOURFILENAME.TXT) do (
    SET s=%%a
    SET s=!s:;= !
    SET s=!s:- =-;;!
    SET s=!s: -=-!
    SET s=!s:-;;-=-;-!
    echo !s!
)
```

will echo `-state of product-;-201705-;-ID1-;-SOLD-;-4-;-PROD 1-;;`

if you want to write each modified line back to a file, then just echo it to file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (YOURFILENAME.TXT) do (
    SET s=%%a
    SET s=!s:;= !
    SET s=!s:- =-;;!
    SET s=!s: -=-!
    SET s=!s:-;;-=-;-!
    echo !s!
) >> NewFile.txt
```

You need to copy the above script, paste in `txt`file then rename the file as `mybatch.cmd` or `mybatch.bat` Change the `MYFILENAME.TXT` in the script to the name of your txt file where the lines `-state;of;product-;-201705-;-ID1-;-SOLD-;-4-;-PROD;1-;;` place the `mybatch` in the same directory as this file. double click the `mybatch` file. Once it is done, there will  be a file called `NewFile.txt` which will contain the edited text.

Ok, forget about the above for now. on your PC open `cmd.exe` then copy everything below and then right click and paste into `cmd.exe` window. It will create a file for you in economic_changes called MyBatch.cmd double click and wait for it to finish. Now see file New_economic_changes.txt in the directory.

```
echo @echo off > "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo setlocal enabledelayedexpansion >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo for /f "delims=" %%a in (economic_changes.txt) do ( >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo    SET s=%%a >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo    SET s=!s:;= ! >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo    SET s=!s:- =-;;! >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo    SET s=!s: -=-! >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo    SET s=!s:-;;-=-;-! >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo    echo !s! >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"
echo ) >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\New_economic_changes.txt" >> "%userprofile%\desktop\Economic_Folder\MyBatch.cmd"

pause
```

Comment: if i write on the cmd: for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    SET s=%%a
    SET s=!s:;= !
    SET s=!s:- =-;;!
    SET s=!s: -=-!
    SET s=!s:-;;-=-;-!
    echo !s!
) it is not doing anything

Comment: are you putting the filename in place of `file.txt`? Is the batch file in the same directory as the txt file? Also, this is a batch file. So you need to copy everything into a text file, save it with extention `.cmd` or `.bat` and put it in the same directory as the txt file. then put the filename in place of where I put `file.txt`

Comment: the txt is created on a batch. it would be possible to write or /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    SET s=%%a
    SET s=!s:;= !
    SET s=!s:- =-;;!
    SET s=!s: -=-!
    SET s=!s:-;;-=-;-!
    echo !s!
) >> my route and make the changes? or i am missing something?

Comment: what is the exact path and filename of your txt file? If you give it, I will write you the code to create the batch file for you.

Comment: the path is on a folder of my Desktop named Economic_Folder. and the txt file is economic_changes.txt

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "STRING=-state;of;product-;-201705-;-ID1-;-SOLD-;-4-;-PROD;1-;;"

echo original: !STRING!

rem // Replace every `-` by `"`, enclose whole string in `""`:
set ^"STRING="!STRING:-="!"" & rem/ odd number of " deranges syntax highlighting!
rem /* Let a `for` loop dismantle the string; since `;` is a token separator
rem    (like ` `, `,`, `=`), the loop divides the string at that characters;
rem    every token separator that appears in a pair of `""` is maintained;
rem    the string portions are reassembled, separated by spaces: */
set "RETURN= "
for %%I in (!STRING!) do set "RETURN=!RETURN!%%I "
rem // Remove surrounding `""` as well as leading and trailing space:
set "RETURN=!RETURN:~2,-2!"
rem // Replace every `"` by `-`:
set ^"RETURN=!RETURN:"=-!" & rem/ odd number of " deranges syntax highlighting!

echo modified: !RETURN!

endlocal
```